Origin of ideal gas fluid dynamics equations including the adiabatic index
I was given a system of equations that supposedly describes the fluid dynamics of an ideal gas.
The equations are:
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\rho}{m} = \frac{p}{T}  &\text{(ideal gas law)} \\\\
&\vec{\nabla} \cdot (\rho \vec{v}) = 0 &\text{(mass conservation)} \\\\
&\rho (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{v} = - \vec{\nabla} p &\text{(momentum conservation)}  \\\\
&\vec{\nabla} \cdot \left[\left( \frac{\rho v^2}{2} + \frac{\gamma p}{\gamma - 1} \right) \vec{v}\right] = Q &\text{(energy conservation)}
\end{align}
$$
With the mass $m$, mass density $\rho$, pressure $p$, flow velocity $\vec{v}$, temperature T (in units of energy by including Boltzmann's constant), the adiabatic index $\gamma$ and an external heat source $Q$.
I am pretty sure that these equations are correct, but I just cannot find a derivation of the last equation.
Can someone tell me where this last equation comes from? Is it correct to call these equations Euler equations or do they have some other name? Especially the term $\gamma p /(\gamma - 1)$ is something I just cannot interpret. The term $\rho v^2/2$ very much looks like a kinetic energy term but how is the pressure relevant in determining the energy?
Additionally, what are the approximations and assumptions underlying this system of equations?

General expression of energy equation reads
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\rho e^t \right) + \nabla \cdot \left( \rho e^t \mathbf{u} \right) = \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \nabla \cdot \left( \mathbb{T} \cdot \mathbf{u} \right) - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q} + \rho r \ ,$$
with $e^t = e + \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2}$ the total energy, $\mathbf{g}$ the force per unit mass, $\mathbb{T} = - p \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{S}$ the stress tensor, $\mathbf{q}$ the heat flux, $r$ the heat source per unit mass.
Some assumptions. With the assumptions of (1) stationary condition $\partial_t \equiv 0$, (2) no volume force $\mathbf{g} = \mathbf{0}$, (3) no viscous stress $\mathbb{S} = 0$, (4) no conduction heat flux $\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{0}$, the energy equation becomes
$$\rho r = \nabla \cdot \left[ \left( \rho e^t + P \right) \mathbf{u} \right] =  \nabla \cdot \left[ \left( \rho e + P + \rho \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} \right) \mathbf{u} \right] =  \nabla \cdot \left[ \left( \rho h + \rho \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} \right) \mathbf{u} \right] \ ,$$
being $h$ the entalphy per unit mass.
Ideal gas. For an ideal gas
$$P = \rho R T \quad , \quad e = c_v T \quad , \quad h = c_P T \ ,$$
and using the definition of the specific heat ratio and Meyer relation
$$\gamma = \frac{c_P}{c_v}  \quad , \quad c_P = R + c_v$$
$$\quad \rightarrow \quad 1 = \frac{c_P}{c_P} = \frac{R}{c_P} + \frac{c_v}{c_P} = \frac{R}{c_P} + \frac{1}{\gamma} \quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{c_P}{R} = \frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1}$$
it's possible to write enthalpy per unit mass as
$$h = c_P T = c_P \frac{P}{\rho R} = \frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1}\frac{P}{\rho} \ .$$
Using this expression in the already simplified equation, we get the desired form of the equation,
$$\rho r =  \nabla \cdot \left[ \left( \frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}P + \rho \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} \right) \mathbf{u} \right]$$

anonymous downvoting = LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL
